# Java: Most efficient way to find matching object values in two ArrayLists?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, match

I have two ArrayLists of objects: `modelList` which contains `Model` objects, and `entityList` which contains `Entity` objects. Both `Model` and `Entity` objects have a property called `id`.

My goal is to loop through each `Model` in `modelList` and, if there is an `Entity` in `entityList` with the same `id` value, call the method `merge()`.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
for (Model model : modelList) {
    for (Entity entity : entityList) {
        if (model.getId().equals(entity.getId())) merge(entity, model);
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem very efficient, especially with a large dataset. What would be a better way of achieving the desired result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As Rene answered, hashing is usually faster than traversing a list.

Comment: list1.retainAll(List2) should do it for you.

Comment: Thank you. The retainAll() method will not work in this case, since Model and Entity are two different object classes.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Map<IdType, Entity>` for the `Entity` objects that maps the `id` to the `Entity`.

Maybe you can change the code that produces the `List<Entity>` to return a `Map`

Comment: This puts me on the right track, I think...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could build a Map models of your Model and search in it.

```
for(Entity entity: entityList) {
    Model model = models.get(entity.getId());
    if (model != null) {
        merge(entity, model);
    }
}
```

This work if you have much less model than entity!

Comment: Thank you. In this case, entity.getId() would not return a value that works as a parameter for modelList.get().

Answer (score 0):

Based on René's answer, I went with this:

```
Map<String, Model> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Model>();
for (Model model : modelList)
    if (!modelMap.containsKey(model.getKey())) modelMap.put(model.getKey(), model);

Iterator it = entityList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Entity entity = (Entity) it.next();
    String key = entity.getKey();
    if (modelMap.containsKey(key)) merge(entity, modelMap.get(key));
    else it.remove();
}
```

Still open to improved answers...